# image preview dropzone mess up

Tags: jquery, dropzone.js

i want to ask about dropzone js.
so i have a upload for image. and i want to make it full fit on the box.
it can fit on the box with setting width and remove padding in dropzone.css, but i dont know why the image preview look messed up. and i can't change the image (which already uploaded) because i remove the default padding. any suggestion guys. thank you. GBU

heres my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/f3uv78rx/7/

heres my script

```
maxFiles: 1,
init: function() {
      this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file) {
            this.removeAllFiles();
            this.addFile(file);
      });
  },
```